# KeyError: 'val_acc' on printing history.history.keys() in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(), metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit_generator(train_generator, batch_size, epochs=epochs)

print(history.history.keys())
```

This results in: ['acc', 'loss']

```
accuracy = history.history['acc']
val_accuracy = history.history['val_acc']
loss = history.history['loss']
val_loss = history.history['val_loss']
epochs = range(len(accuracy))
```

This generates the error: KeyError: 'val_acc'

Why can't I see val_acc and val_loss in history.history.keys() ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not providing any validation data to `model.fit()`, so there is no validation data to compute `val_acc`. You'll need to add validation data to your training loop:

```
history = model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                              batch_size, 
                              epochs,
                              validation_data=validation_generator)
```

Comment: Hello, so should I initialize validation_generator with gen.flow(x_test, y_test, batch_size=batch_size) ?

Comment: It is generating an error: raise ValueError('`validation_steps=None` is only valid for a'
ValueError: `validation_steps=None` is only valid for a generator based on the `keras.utils.Sequence` class. Please specify `validation_steps` or use the `keras.utils.Sequence` class.

Comment: It looks like now it is `val_accuracy`

Answer (score 3):

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                                       metrics=['accuracy'])
rnn = model.fit(X_train, y_train, nb_epoch= nb_epoch, batch_size=batch_size, 
                               shuffle=True, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
score = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
print("Test Loss: %.2f%%" % (score[0]*100))
print("Test Accuracy: %.2f%%" % (score[1]*100))
```